# how to use eonet api to get natural disaster image using python

Tags: python

I have been trying to use EONET documentation to get natural disaster images but it is difficult to understand the documentation.So can anybody help me how to use eonet api using python?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what EONET is exactly, a link perhaps? Many of us here will not be familiar with it.

Comment: It is a NASA API used for getting natural disaster images link:https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/v2.1